# Hours in Ternary operator giving opposite result? Could a %12 be the culprit?

Tags: javascript, time, modulo, conditional-operator

I am a newbie so please so show mercy!

I am making a digital clock for bootcamp. I am getting the hours from .gethours(), and I also am requesting a % 12 to make it a 12 hour time clock.  However when I run my dayNight ternary operator, I'm getting an output of PM for <=12. Could the modulo be causing this issue somehow?

```js
function awesomeClock() {
  var date = new Date();
  var hours = date.getHours() % 12; /* get hours modulo 12 to see if there is a remainder to set 12 hour time clock*/
  var minutes = date.getMinutes();
  var seconds = date.getSeconds();
  var dayNight = (hours <= 12) ? "AM" : "PM"; /* Ternary operator, greater than 12 hours = PM */
    
 

  if (hours < 10){
      hour = "0" + hour;
  }

  if (minutes  < 10){
      minutes = "0" + minutes;
  }

  if (seconds < 10){
      seconds = "0" + seconds;
  }


  document.getElementById("awesomeClock").innerHTML = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + " " + dayNight;

  setInterval(awesomeClock, 1000); /* Sets interval to 1000 milliseconds which is 1 second,
   so the page is always refreshing. */
} 

awesomeClock();
```

```html
<div id="awesomeClock"></div>
```

Comment: `hours = date.getHours() % 12` will mean that `hours` is always less than 12, so `AM` will always be printed? (It's PM where I am right now, and it's indeed printing AM, which it shouldn't be)

Comment: Yes, PM here as well. I thought I was being clever early on with my code but I must be crossing the wires sadly.

Comment: So do you mean that this is a typo? *However when I run my dayNight ternary operator, I'm getting an output of PM for <=12.* Did you mean *However when I run my dayNight ternary operator, I'm getting an output of AM for >12.*? Getting PM *shouldn't* be possible

Comment: No, I wrote my description correctly, but I realize now that the hours will always be 12 or less due to my modulo, so the value will always be AM.

Comment: Your description says *I'm getting an output of PM for <=12.* but such an output should be impossible given the code in the question...

Comment: You are correct. The clock stopped at 11:59:59. The code is busted and moduelo cant be used. Im going to have to make an if statement for the 12 hour clock. Thanks for your help and patience!

Answer (score 0):

As stated in comments you are having little wrong logic while finding AM or PM.
You can use below snippit code to improve that:

```js
var hours = date.getHours();
var hoursInAMPM = hours % 12; /* get hours modulo 12 to see if there is a remainder to set 12 hour time clock*/
var dayNight = (hours < 12) ? "AM" : "PM"; /* Ternary operator, greater than 12 hours = PM */
```

```js
function awesomeClock() {
  var date = new Date();
  var hours = date.getHours();
  var hoursInAMPM = hours % 12; /* get hours modulo 12 to see if there is a remainder to set 12 hour time clock*/
  var dayNight = (hours < 12) ? "AM" : "PM"; /* Ternary operator, greater than 12 hours = PM */

  var minutes = date.getMinutes();
  var seconds = date.getSeconds();


  if (hoursInAMPM < 10) {
    hoursInAMPM = "0" + hoursInAMPM;
  }

  if (minutes < 10) {
    minutes = "0" + minutes;
  }

  if (seconds < 10) {
    seconds = "0" + seconds;
  }


  document.getElementById("awesomeClock").innerHTML = hoursInAMPM + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + " " + dayNight;

  setInterval(awesomeClock, 1000);
  /* Sets interval to 1000 milliseconds which is 1 second,
    so the page is always refreshing. */
}

awesomeClock();
```

```html
<div id="awesomeClock"></div>
```